# retrieving form values from NewForm.aspx?source=/_layouts/blah.aspx

Tags: splistitem, list-form

I'm building a system that shows a list's NewForm.aspx to an anonymous website visitor, which they can complete and submit. The URL to the form includes `"?source=/_layouts/blah.aspx"`, so after the list has been updated with a new item, this `blah.aspx` page is called and can do other operations.

My question is, on `blah.aspx`, how can I get the values of the fields submitted as part of the form?

e.g.

1. My list "QMKevin-List" has 3 fields: Title (text(, Email (text), OptOut (checkbox)
2. NewForm.aspx shows these 3 fields, which I fill in and then I submit the form
3. QMKevin-List is updated with a new list item
4. /_layouts/blah.aspx is called, and let's say I want to send an email to whoever filled out the form

from `blah.aspx`, how can I get the email address of whoever completed the form? remember, this form is shown to anonymous visitors to my site, so they are not logged in (no SPContext.Current.User...)

Also, if `blah.aspx` wanted to update the list item, is there any way to get the item.id of the newly created item, so that I know exactly which item to update? this is in case someone complete the form twice with the same info.. I need that unique identifier so I know which item to update.

Comment: Is this a totally custom solution or are you trying to stick with Out of the Box features?  Which version of SharePoint are you using?  Does the user need to interact more with blah.aspx?

Comment: It's not a totally custom solution, but it is a custom form for a list, and is a custom processing page (blah.aspx) that the user ends up at. I'm using SharePoint Server 2010 (sorry, I should have mentioned that). No, the user doesn't need to interact with blah.aspx, but I need to use the values entered into the form and saved to the list, when blah.aspx is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code-behind of the form you are allowed a lot of diffent ways to store temporary data (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx) You could also write to database,...

In your case I would use the session state:

> Application state is a global storage mechanism that is accessible
>   from all pages in the Web application. Thus, application state is
>   useful for storing information that needs to be maintained between
>   server round trips and between requests for pages.
>
> Session state is similar to application state, except that it is
>   scoped to the current browser session. If different users are using
>   your application, each user session will have a different session
>   state. In addition, if a user leaves your application and then returns
>   later, the second user session will have a different session state
>   from the first.

Example:

Store in NewForm.aspx:

```
Session.Contents["Email"] = "this.is.my@email.com";
```

Get value in blah.aspx:

```
string email = Session.Contents["Email"];
```

For more info, see
[Msdn session state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87069683%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for that, Ruben. I ended up using JavaScript to add values to the "source" URL, which I can then use to identify the newly created list item. Similar to your approach, in that passing info can then be used either directly on blah.aspx, or can be used to identify the list item.. just using a more basic (and potentially less robust) method. Still, you answer is the better of the two, so marked as the answer :)